# How to initiate remote desktop access session from machine to control it from another machine?

Tags: remote-access

Assume our windows 7 machine A has no public IP - it's connected to LAN and has IP like 192.168. This machine has access to Internet. How to initiate remote access from this server machine A to be able manipulate of desktop of A by client machine B the same way RDP allows or something like that? Machine B has public IP and is connected somewhere in Internet - not in the same LAN with A. So there is possibility to establish connection from A to B but not possible from B to A. A should be controlled by B. In other words I should be capable to begin session from A and later work remotely from B with A's desktop. Updated: I have admin control only on my machine A and B.

Comment: If you upgrade your network to dual stack, the machine will have a public IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly something like TeamViewer or Splashtop seems like a perfectly good solution for this. I'm not aware of any reverse rdp tunnel capabilities with windows.

Or, at the router level, you could enable port forwarding to your machine on the RDP port and enable Remote Desktop but you said you only have machine admin and that requires network level configuration.

Comment: It's a pity but I have admin control only on my machine A and B.

Comment: Then TeamViewer or Splashtop is my bet @Parfen

Comment: I think for desktop to desktop teamviewer is better. I work at a small IT company and we use (the corporate license version) teamviewer to provide remote support. It's pretty nice.

Comment: For either one if you have the option to make an account, make one. Makes management a lot easier than using computer IDs

Comment: Great - TeamViewer works on my two virtual machines - I can control one from another. Have you any idea of architecture of TeamViewer? There are lots of restrictions in my real network (will discover only on Monday) - so I'm afraid whther it will work. Do they use some shared middle server in Internet to establish connection? Then hosts should have access to this server - traffic should not be blocked.

Comment: It'll probably make a firewall exception or something, but I believe it it reacts with a median server to get past the NAT. I won't have the chance to look at it tonight probably but I'll monitor a session today or tomorrow.

Comment: I mean intermediary or whatever. But yeah.

Comment: The big point is that Teamviewer's remote client initiates the session which is a-okay in most firewalled environments since outbound traffic is like never regulated really compared to inbound traffic.

Comment: It depends - from my office machine I can't connect to my home FTP server. I'm not admin - probably it is well-known practice to block outbound traffic to host without DNS name. But I's unlikely - after translating DNS name to IP it is not distinguishable. Or maybe it worth to change port to 80.